# JMeter Thread Group for simulating multiple users joining page at specific intervals

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am currently working on a test plan in JMeter where I need to simulate multiple users joining a webpage at a specific interval. The simulation needs to run for 30 minutes and every 0.7 seconds a new user joins the page, performs an iteration of a feature, and then leaves.

In the iteration of the feature, the user performs 1 to 5 API calls randomly and waits between each call.

I am confused about which thread group would be the best to use for this scenario. Also, I am unsure if threads continue looping after they are done, which might result in more than one user joining every 0.7 seconds.

Can anyone suggest a suitable thread group for this scenario? Also, any suggestions on how to ensure that only one user joins every 0.7 seconds would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the default [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

In order to get the ramp-up period value just multiply your number of threads (virtual users) by `0.7` and you will get the ramp-up period in seconds

I.e.:

- 50 users -> 50 * 0.7  -> 35 seconds
- 100 users -> 100 * 0.7 -> 70 seconds
- etc.

If you want user to "leave" keep the number of iterations as 1. Your test will end when the last user will finish executing the last request.

More information:

- [JMeter Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group)
- [JMeter Ramp-Up Period: The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period)